# JavaScript saving Canvas as a file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been trying to save canvas as a file which sort of having been successful to some extent. Every time I save the file as an image it ended up downloaded blank image file. Yet when I use `//document.write('<img src="'+image+'"/>');` it displays the drawn canvas fine as an image which can be downloadable.

```
function saveFile() {
var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
//document.write('<img src="'+image+'"/>');

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = "image.png";
link.href = image;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
delete link;
};
```

Nothing comes up on the console log.

Can you guys give me any ideas how can I fix this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you sure if `saveFile()` is invoked?

Comment: Yes, it is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the delete operator is unnecessary here since you cannot delete a variable declared with var. That being said, give a try to the below snippet since it is a working solution tested on Firefox and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
</style>
<body>
    <canvas width="480" height="480">
    </canvas>
    <script id="mainScript" type="text/javascript">
        !function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
                img = new Image();
            img.src = "./test.jpg";
            img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this,0,0,480,480);
                var dURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
                    aTag = document.createElement("a");
                aTag.download = "image.png";
                aTag.href = dURL;
                aTag.textContent = "click to download";
                document.body.appendChild(aTag);
                aTag.click();
                aTag.parentNode.removeChild(aTag);
            };
        }();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure that the server sends the proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin header so that the canvas does not become tainted.

One option could be to wrap link removal within a requestAnimationFrame or setTimeout but I doubt it will solve. First give a try to this snippet, then we can see if the issue lies elsewhere. Btw, which browser are you testing this?

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work for me as I don't use canvas Tag, its created within the DOMContent in a div using this tutorial https://github.com/krisrak/html5-canvas-drawing-app/blob/master/index_javascript.html

Comment: The example git you provided still uses the conventional canvas tags. Browsers handle document.write slightly differently. When you say I download a blank image file, that happens usually when the image is not yet loaded. If for some reason, the dataURL string is long, it might help you, to instead in the script above doing img.src = "./test.src" point to your dataURL. So trap the downloading process within an onload handler. Does that work?

Comment: This is no longer an issue as I have switched to Canvas2Image as Phonegap doesn't support this method. Thank you, I will mark your answer as the right answer because it worked on the browser.